# WebHDFS Kerberos - HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, spnego

I've installed kerberos for my hadoop cluster and now want to use webhdfs via curl. For some reason the authentication doesn't work. I've a valid ticket for the user who has r/w on file1 in HDFS in my kerberos ticket cache.

```
hadoop@hadoop-name:~$ curl -i --negotiate -u:anyUser -L "http://hadoop-name:9870/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/file1?op=OPEN"

HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; Domain=HADOOP.LOCAL; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 482

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Authentication required</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Authentication required</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/file1</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Authentication required</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-4c6daf0</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does a ticket for `HTTP/hadoop-name` show up in your ticket cache after this command? Can you re-run it with `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr` in the environment?

Comment: What is ...-u:anyUser... in your curl command? AFAIK, when trying GSS-negotiate auth, you should NOT specify userid:password in -u so that curl create delegation token based on kerberos ticket cache. I.e. a colon should be surrounded by spaces, like `curl -i --negotiate -u : -L http://.....`